# filehandle options not coming up

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfilemanager, filehandle

I have typed the following code in from a tutorial and i cannot get it to work...
It says "No visible @interface for 'NSFilemanager' declares the selector ..... 
for the [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile]; [fileHandle writeData:[resultLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]]; [fileHandle closeFile]; sections..

Any idea what the problem is as ive gone through it many many times..
Thanks
Mat

```
 - (IBAction)SaveText:(id)sender {

NSString *resultLine =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",
                       self.inputText];

NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES)objectAtIndex:0];
// textMsg.text = docPath;

NSString *savedTextMsg =[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"textMessage.csv"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
     createFileAtPath:savedTextMsg contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
NSFileManager *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:savedTextMsg];
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:[resultLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]];
[fileHandle closeFile];

self.textMsg.text =@"";
NSLog(@"info saved");
```

}

Comment: Look at your code a bit better :) The mistake is obvious.

Comment: i changed fileHandle to something else and it worked! cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you changed:

```
NSFileManager *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:savedTextMsg];
```

to:

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:savedTextMsg];
```

Note the variable's type.

Comment: hA!:-) or am I missing something??